# How to move values from one array to another in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have two arrays

```
var shoppingList = ["bread","milk"];
var boughtItems = [];
```

If I wanted to move an item from one array to the other, how would I go about that?

For example:

```
function purchaseItem (item) {
    boughtItems.push( shoppingList.splice( shoppingList.indexOf( item ),1 );
}
```

Comment: Why not create a new array with the item(s) you want? You can use `filter` for that

Comment: Should be just like you have it but I would have the push/splice operations separated for readability. Also, don't know if you tried that code above, but you're missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `)` and also you need to get first item like this

```
function purchaseItem (item) {
    boughtItems.push( shoppingList.splice( shoppingList.indexOf(item),1)[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boughtItems.push(shoppingList[IndexOfThingYouWantPushed]);
```

But remember Arrays start from Index `0`, so the first index in an array is `0`, the next index of `1`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set` for this, it is much more logically concise and also constant insertion / deltetion.

```
var list = new Set(['bread', 'milk']);
var bought = new Set;
function purchaseItem(item) {
  list.delete(item);
  bought.add(item);
}
```